# Vuejs Data Update

Tags: highcharts, vuejs2

I am trying to update highcharts data from a vuex-store, but the issue is that when the click event is triggered, the data in the vuex store state is mutated, but it only reflects in my highcharts component when i make some changes to the code and save the changes.

**I am working on a dashboard using Vue and Highcharts.**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-highcharts :options="options" ref="lineCharts"></vue-highcharts>
    <v-btn>{{parts}}</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueHighcharts from 'vue2-highcharts';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {

  components: {
    VueHighcharts,

  },
  data() {
    return {

      options: {
        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          title: 'Hassaan',
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: '',
          },
          labels: {
            formatter() {
              return `${this.value}°`;
            },
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          crosshairs: true,
          shared: true,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          spline: {
            marker: {
              radius: 4,
              lineColor: '#666666',
              lineWidth: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        series: [],
      },
    };
  },


  created() {
    Vue.set(this.options, 'series', this.$store.state.parts);
  },

};
</script>
```

I want the data to be updated without making any changes to the code and saving it.

Comment: In where you are using your `series` array?

Comment: @SajibKhan I am using it for the highacharts

Comment: Could you reproduce your app/chart in online code editor like codesandbox or stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `computed` to get the value with reactivity from the store, that way you don't need the `created` hook anymore. Also you should never access values from your store directly through the state, instead create a getter.

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, however this should be the right structure. If you only want to set `this.options.series = this.$store.getters.parts`. Like you are already doing with the `Vue.set(this.options, 'series', this.$store.state.parts)`, in that case, add a watcher for the computed property and set the new property value.

```
{
  watch: {
    parts (updatedParts) {
      this.series.parts = updatedParts;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    parts () {
      return this.$store.getters.parts;
    }
  }
}
```